# Directory resets on git push

Tags: node.js, linux, github, pm2, github-actions

i'm currently having a problem with the enviroment variables of my droplet in digital ocean, the problem is the following: if i set an env variable with the `export PORT=3000` it applies for all my apps(i have more than one app in the same droplet), so that throws an error because it can only have one app listening on one port, if i set the env variables with a .env file and the dotenv package, everytime i push a new commit(i am using github actions for auto deploy), the repository resets and the .env file is deleted, is there any way to set env variables just for one directory or in a way it doesn't gets deleted

this is the way i deploy an app: i create the github action, my droplet listen to the changes on the repository, with pm2 i keep the app listening to a specific port and with nginx i use subdomains as proxy to show the correct app for that subdomain

Comment: There are many ways. It's usually done outside of, or in addition to the git code repo as one app normally maps to multiple environments. Can you provide some more detailed info and examples of how you run the applications? and deploy them?

Comment: @Matt i updated the question with more info about how i deploy the apps, they are currently working, the only problem is that when i push anything to the repo, all the env variables are gone as they were on the .env file

Comment: What does this mean exactly? "the repository resets and the .env file is deleted"

Comment: `.env` is in your `.gitignore` so it doesn't get pushed out to your droplet. Note that removing `.env` from your gitignore is not necessarily a good solution either.

Comment: @RobertMoskal every time i push a commit, because of the github actions, the repository kinda resets, every file that wasn´t in the repository gets deleted

Comment: @MartinMunilla what github action are you using? you could let the github action create an .env folder in the repository taking the secrets from github action secrets, or not delete the .env folder on each deploy

Answer (score 0):

I'm understanding that you aren't committing your .env to your repository.

This is a best practice and keeps keeps your secrets safer (as an attacker would have to gain access to your DO droplet to get at them).

In your situation, and especially if  your git repository is private, the simplest solution might just be to have the .env file in git. If you're only storing configuration info in the environment, there's no reason not to (except maybe others might judge you harshly for it).

Your workflow stays exactly the same, except you don't have to keep recreating your .env file every time you run your github actions.

If, for whatever reason, you don't want to go that route then a couple of low tech solutions come to mind:

If there are only a few configs  and if you are comfortable with the risk, you can simply prepend the env variable to the node start command of each application:

```
PORT=300 KEY2=foo node app1.js
```

If you have a lot of common shared configs, you could continue EXPORTing them to the  environment and then override per application settings, like ports,  using the above technique.

You also could place all your .env files in a directory on the droplet like so:

```
/var/configs/app1.env
/var/configs/app2.env
```

Then you could start each node app with a command line that looks like this:

```
node -r dotenv/config your_script.js dotenv_config_path=/var/configs/app2.env
```

Either technique will quickly get you a workable deployment workflow. But, if you are exposing sensitive or valuable secrets, consider using a secret management system.  You can start with the one github has just introduced: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets.